# org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeOutException: The host did not accept the connection with in timeout of 20000 ms

Tags: java, network-programming, applet, httpclient, connection-timeout

Hi i am trying connect httpcleint using

```
                    client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(20000);        client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(20000);  
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(20000);  
                    client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(20000);  
                    try  
                    {  
                       int returncode = client.executeMethod(post);

                      System.out.println("returncode : " + returncode);
                            System.out.println("responseString:"+post.getResponseBodyAsString());  
                    }  
                    catch (Exception e)  
                    {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  

                    System.out.println("Exception e : ");
                     System.err.println(e);
                     System.out.println("END Exception e : ");
                    }  

                    finally  
                    {  
                        post.releaseConnection();  
                    }
```

i am getting below in my log as

network: Connecting http://lt-ua-ed:7090/ with proxy=Direct connection 
java.net.ConnectException: Connectiontimed out:connect.....

timeout exception with connecting  URl lt-ua-ed:7090

i already confirmed that there is not blocking in firewall also.
Please can anyone help me to identify causes for these issue with steps since, i am new for java environment.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a telnet on port 7090 of `lt-ua-ed`?

Comment: you mean i need to try from client machi right?

Comment: Open terminal, enter `telnet lt-ua-ed 7090` - if it errors out with a timeout, your machine cannot reach that server.